# Can we please have the full list shown in Hide Communities?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, hidden-communities

The “Hide Communities” only shows 12 out of however many visible communities I have. This makes it extremely difficult to figure out which ones are unhidden, as the Network Profile list doesn’t show which one is hidden and which one isn’t.

Please allow for showing/expanding the full list, so it’s easy to click Hide next to those one wants to hide, same as Unhide works for the already hidden ones. Otherwise, the [feature meant to unclutter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/260254/234382) is unusable because it’s cluttered up itself.

Comment: Hidden Communities is a messed-up scene, man.

Comment: I tend to agree with @Nathan - this whole thing appears to be some kind of new experiment introduced with the new profile page design, and it's causing more confusion and frustration than good, as far as I can tell.